# Soma and Vajapeya Yagnas

Tags: yajna

What is the purpose, modality and purported benefits of the above   Vedic/Yagnyas/procedures handed down  to us ? Are they performed in the exact Yogic way in modern times too?

The Soma Yagnya is in appeasement/worship of Shiva and the latter is to Indra but that is all one gets to know..

Comment: vedic yagas are for vedic deities mainly like indra , agni varuna mitra etc